# Creating symbolic link in a Databricks FileStore's folder

Tags: databricks, symlink, ln

I would like to create a symbolic link like in linux env with the command : **ln -s**.
Unfortunately I can't find anything similar to do in a Databricks FileStore.
And it seems that **ln** operation is not a member of **dbutils**.

Is there a way to do this maybe differently?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileStore` is located on DBFS (Databricks File System) that is baked either by S3, or ADLS that don't have a notion of symlink.  You have a choice - either rename file, or copy it, or modify your code to generate correct file name from an alias.